# Could my iPhone be installing malware on factory reset?

Tags: ios, malware

Hi I have an iPhone 7s and have been doing the factory reset, erase all content, data, and settings option. Every time I do this I get three loading bars, not the normal two like my other phone. The first loading bar is normal and under the apple logo. The second loading bar however happens after the first loading bar finishes, then the apple logo is the only thing on screen, then the spinning circles occurs, then a mini loading bar appears with nothing else on the screen. After the mini loading bar is done the final loading bar with the apple icon above finishes and the phone boots to the hello start page to put my information back in.

Is this normal and if it isnt what happened. I have never jail broken my device but I did find a video that showcases the mini loading bar, albeit it looks like he has two loading bars, not three. Time stamp is 3:20 to see mini loading bar.

What should I do?

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kHSIe8aze78

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely normal to see loading bars / progress while the phone reboots after a "factory reset". It is not a sign of malware being installed.

Perhaps your suspicion is because your phone is managed - i.e. owned and controlled by your employer, school, or similar?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i only ask because before it was doing two loading bars and now I have three. And since it’s a mini loading bar it made me worried it was third party. I am not very technologically inclined and I always see great answers about stuff from stack exchange so I thought I would make an account and ask it here. :p the phone is my personal by the way